# Timer in SignalR overlaps when another group enters into hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, timer, signalr, signalr-hub

I have created a signalR hub which is solving purpose to show timer at UI of grouped person. If one person starts a play with another one, timer runs very nice.

But the problem is when another group start a new play and previous one is still in progress, I mean Timer is already running, then it overlaps the timer and hold one group. Timer runs once at a time. But I want it to have threading and run for every group.

here is my code:

ConnectionMapping.cs

```
public class ConnectionMapping<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>> _connections = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>();

    public int Count { get { return _connections.Count; } }

    public void Add(T key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                connections = new HashSet<string>();
                _connections.Add(key, connections);
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Add(connectionId);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetConnections(T key)
    {
        HashSet<string> connections;
        if (_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
        {
            return connections;
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    public void Remove(T key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Remove(connectionId);

                if (connections.Count == 0)
                {
                    _connections.Remove(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a Hub class:

```
public class TimeSyncingHub : Hub
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapping<int> _connections = new ConnectionMapping<int>();
    private readonly PlayerPickTicker _playerPickTicker;
    private readonly object _PickStateLock = new object();
    private IUserBusiness userBusiness;

    public TimeSyncingHub() :
        this(PlayerPickTicker.Instance)
    {

    }
    public TimeSyncingHub(PlayerPickTicker playerPickTicker)
    {
        _playerPickTicker = playerPickTicker;
    }

    public Task LeaveRoom(string roomName)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    }

    public async Task JoinRoom(string roomName)
    {
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
        Clients.Group(roomName).JoinedRoom("Enter into group - " + roomName);
    }
}
```

Another class where I have written time code is **PlayerPickTicker** class which is depends in same and implemented in constructor of hub class as shown in class above.

Below is PlayerPickTicker class:

```
public class PlayerPickTicker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly static Lazy<PlayerPickTicker> _instance = new Lazy<PlayerPickTicker>(
       () => new PlayerPickTicker(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TimeSyncingHub>()));

    private IHubContext _context;
    public UserPlayerPickModel UserPlayerPick { get; set; }
    public static PlayerPickTicker Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }
private Timer TickTimer;
    private Timer InitialTickTimer;
    public int StartSeconds { get; set; }
    public int StopSeconds { get; set; }

    public bool IsTimerOver { get; set; }

    private PlayerPickTicker(IHubContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }


    public void StartInitialTimer(Model.QueryModel queryModel)
    {
        try
        {
            MyDraftBusiness myDraft = new MyDraftBusiness();
            myDraft.UdpatePlaysOneMinuteTimerPending(queryModel);

            //lock (_InitialTimerStateLock)
            //{
            //StartSeconds = 60;
            //if (InitialTickTimer != null)
            //{
            //    InitialTickTimer.Dispose();
            //}
            States = new Dictionary<string, bool>() {
                    { "IsInitialTimerOver", false},
                    { "CallInitialTimerOverMethod", true},
                };

            PickPlayer = new Dictionary<string, long>() { { "LastPlayerPickId", 0 } };
            //lock (States)
            //{
            StartSeconds = 60;
            StopSeconds = 0;
            IsInitialTimerOver = false;
            CallInitialTimerOverMethod = true;
            //}

            InitialTickTimer = new Timer();// OnTimerElapsedInitialTimer, queryModel, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            InitialTickTimer.Interval = 1000;
            InitialTickTimer.Enabled = true;
            InitialTickTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => OnTimerElapsedInitialTimer(queryModel, e);
            InitialTickTimer.AutoReset = false;
            //}
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.ExceptionsLog.LogFile(" -( At StartInitialTimer Mehtod )- " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsedInitialTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Model.QueryModel queryModel = (Model.QueryModel)sender;
        try
        {
            //lock (_InitialtickStateLock)
            //{
            var states = (Dictionary<string, bool>)States;
            var IsInitialTimerOver = states.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "IsInitialTimerOver").Value;
            //Clients.
            if (StartSeconds <= StopSeconds && !IsInitialTimerOver)
            {
                if (InitialTickTimer != null)
                {
                    InitialTickTimer.Dispose();
                }
                //IsInitialTimerOver = true;
                states["IsInitialTimerOver"] = true;
                //lock (States)
                //{
                //************** from client to server                        
                var JsonResult = new JObject();
                JsonResult.Add("data", JToken.FromObject(queryModel));

                string GroupName = "Group" + queryModel.playId.ToString();
                _context.Clients.Group(GroupName).initialTimerCompleted(JsonResult);

                //_context.Clients.Group(GroupName, _context.Clients.All).initialTimerCompleted(JsonResult);
                //_context.Clients.All.initialTimerCompleted(JsonResult);

                MyDraftBusiness myDraft = new MyDraftBusiness();
                try
                {
                    myDraft.UdpatePlaysOneMinuteTimerRunning(queryModel);
                    DraftModel draftModel = myDraft.GetDraftById(queryModel);
                    if (draftModel != null)
                    {
                        var userPlayerPicks = myDraft.GetUserPlayerPickByPlayId(draftModel.PlayId);

                        if (draftModel.IsDraftFilled)
                        {
                            if (draftModel.Play != null && draftModel.Play.IsOneMinuteTimerPending == true)
                            {
                                myDraft.UdpatePlaysOneMinuteTimerPending(queryModel);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var activeUserPick = userPlayerPicks.Where(x => !x.Picked).FirstOrDefault();
                                if (activeUserPick != null)
                                {
                                    StartTimer(activeUserPick);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Helpers.ExceptionsLog.LogFile(" -( At OnTimerElapsedInitialTimer Mehtod inner catch )- " + ex.Message);
                    var userPlayerPicks = myDraft.GetUserPlayerPickByPlayId(queryModel.playId);
                    var activeUserPick = userPlayerPicks.Where(x => !x.Picked).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (activeUserPick != null)
                    {
                        StartTimer(activeUserPick);
                    }
                }
                //}
            }
            else if (StartSeconds > 0)
            {
                //IsInitialTimerOver = false;
                states["IsInitialTimerOver"] = false;
                //lock (States)
                //{
                StartSeconds -= 1;
                var GroupName = "Group" + Convert.ToString(queryModel.playId);
                _context.Clients.Group(GroupName).intialTimerElapsed(StartSeconds);
                _context.Clients.All.pickRunning(queryModel.playId);
                InitialTickTimer.Stop();
                InitialTickTimer.Start();
                //StartInitialTimer(queryModel);
                //}
            }
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.ExceptionsLog.LogFile(" -( At OnTimerElapsedInitialTimer Mehtod )- " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I know it's big code and hard to understand. But I hope for **Any Good Developer** here, Much appreciation for helper from core of my heart!

Comment: Well, your code seems to be set up to ensure that only one instance of `PlayerPickTimer` can exist - so what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I want to have multiple instance when its on server, but currently timer overrides when there is new user starts a play.

Comment: I mean it stops the previous timer and signal R won't able to send any tick and starts new one for new user and send them signal.